# Error opening libpython3.9.s0.1.0 on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a program that was originally compiled for x86 processors on my raspberry pi, I tried to use the box86 emulator which I installed to launch it but it is returning a long list of errors of the following type.

"Error: Global Symbol XML_SetEncoding not found, cannot apply R_386_BLOB_DAT @0xba19f98 ((nil)) in ~/program/libpython3.9.so.1.0"

and ending with

"Error loading Python lib '/program/libpython3.9.so.1.0': dlopen Cannot dlopen("/program/libpython3.9.so.1.0"/0xb6380560, 102)

I can't find any reference to these type of errors and am unsure if it is something in the setup or due to the box86 emulator? The program I am running is initialised from a .sh and runs a python script, and the libpython3.9.so.1.0 file is located in the directory it is looking in.

I know this is not the best way to go about this but I have been tasked with getting the program running on a pi and if it proves impossible I can try to purchase an industrial pc for the task but I would like to try with this first, My next step will be attempting to see if using exagear may help but assistance with these errors would be useful first.

Edit: I have not done any configuration of python or the path since setting up the Pi, however the file i am running starts with #!/usr/bin/env/ bash

Comment: From the error it looks like it it searching under `/program/` as in the absolute path not relative to the folder you are in

Comment: Yes it is looking absolute I think, is that an issue? It's still looking in the right place.